# Insert large amount of data into MongoDB collection with Doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm

I am using Doctrine and MongoDB for an application and there is one task that should import data from an CSV file into a collection. There are about 5 different CSV files with at least 450.000 entries per file that should be important 1 to 3 times per year.

Currently I iterate through all lines of a file, create an object, call `persist()` and flush every 2.500 items.

Each item is not very large, it has an ID, a string that is 10-20 characters, a string that is 5-10 characters and a boolean value.

My first question is:
When I flush every 5.000 items inserting gets significantly slower. In my test environment flushing 5.000 items took about 102 seconds, flushing 2.500 items took about 10 seconds.

Flushing gets slower after a while. As mentioned, at the beginning flush 2.500 items took about 10 seconds, after 100.000 items, flushing 2.500 items takes nearly one minute.

Are there any optimisations I can do to speed things up?

Comment: How are you reading the CSV file? and Do you clear your EntityManager after flush() operation? If not, that means that every object is stored in memory and makes things slower.

Comment: @BorisGuéry Thanks, that helped a lot. If you add this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are two parts that may be optimized in your script.

- The way you read your CSV files, depending on how you load it, you either totally load it in memory (using `file_get_contents()` or `file()` for example), or reading it chunck by chunck with `fopen()`, `fread()`.

The last option is prefered because it will only take the necessary amount of memory when processing a bunch of lines.

- You need to `clear()` the object you already processed, else it will be kept in memory until the end of your script. This means that if one DC2 object uses 1Mo of memory, and you have 100,000 objects, at the end of your scripts it will use 100,000Mo. 
  So batching your insert by range of 2,500 is quite a good idea but you obviously need to remove the processed object from the EntityManager.

It can be done using `$entityManager->clear();`

The `clear()` will clear the whole `EntityManager`, you want to clear a single entity, you may use `$entityManager->detach($object)`.

---

If you want to profile your memory usage you may also be interested in the functions

[`memory_get_usage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)

[`memory_get_peak_usage()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)

Comment: Reading the files is no problem, it takes about 600MB of memory to read in all lines and convert them into `Document` objects. When I use `clear` it will take about an hour to import all objects, which is fine for my use case (the task only gets executed 1 or 2 times a year)

Comment: Ten years earlier, you would have been fired for using 600Mb of memory to read a file ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason this import script needs to use the Doctrine ODM? For the application as a whole - sure. But handling big ammounts of data with so much overhead is not optimal as PHP is not so efficient in holding and handling big collections.

The best optimization you could do is to skip that layer and use the mongodb classes directly and make sure you read the file line by line rather than all at once. Also using the batchInsert() will speed you up alot if you have some network latency to MongoDB (but you don't ever need to push it to 5k documents).

Comment: It's just convenience to use Doctrine. When I use `clear()` like @Boris Guéry suggested, it works quite well. However, should I not be able to get it down to an acceptable duration I would switch to directly calling MongoDB.

Comment: Well, it is convenient in a normal application situation handling no more than a dozen documents. It does however (as with their ORM) have a huge overhead and with more queries - more overhead. Seems it has already made your situation in the batch script less convenient by making you run over the hill for solutions to the problems it causes. A tip is to strip a Doctrine ODM insert to the bare bottom (insert an int to a new collection or so) and then do the same with a batchInsert with the native drivers - and you will see exactly how much Doctrine is hurting you.